# Assigning the return value of a javascript function is showing as [object Object and not the HTML?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to append some javascript return value to an element on the page.

When appended in the web browser I just see [object Object] inside the DIV.

Any idea where I am going wrong?

JavaScript to append function return value to HTML:

```
let documentTable = this.renderDocuments();
let elem = document.getElementById('TableGoesHere');
elem.innerHTML += documentTable;
```

Render:

```
<div id="TableGoesHere"></div>
```

Console log of documentTable:
[image]

RenderDocuments function:

```
  public renderDocuments() {

    const docs = this.state.documents.map(document => {

      return (
        <tr>
          <td className="title">{document.Cells.results[3].Value }</td>
          <td className="site">{siteName}</td>
          <td className="path">{sitePath}</td>
          <td><a href={document.Cells.results[6].Value + '?web=1&action=edit'}>View File</a></td>
        </tr> 
      )

    });

    return (

      <div id="tableID" className="table-list-container">

        <table className="table-list">

          <thead>
            <th><button type="button" className="sort" data-sort="title">Title</button></th>
            <th><button type="button" className="sort" data-sort="site">Site</button></th>
            <th><button type="button" className="sort" data-sort="path">Path</button></th>
            <th><button type="button">View File</button></th>
          </thead>

          <tbody className="list">

            {docs}

          </tbody>

        </table>

        <table className="table-footer">
          <tr>
            <td className="table-pagination">
              <ul className="pagination"></ul>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>

      </div>

    )

  }
```

Comment: What does `this.renderDocuments()` return? Can you post code for that function too?

Comment: If you are using typescript, is this some framework, like Angular?

Comment: Yes I am using typescript react to create SPFX web parts

Comment: I have added console log of the this.renderDocuments() return

Comment: Can'y you do something like this: <div id="TableGoesHere">{documentTable}</div>
I am no expert of react, bit in VUE or Angular you can print variables in html. Also for Angular there is 'json' pipe. There should be something for typescript react.

Comment: What do you want to display? The entire object? Or a particular value from the object?

Comment: The entire object, it should be a HTML Table with some rows

Comment: but it is not a html table with some rows, it's an object. that's why it's displayed as [Object object]. if you want to display a html table, you have to add an html table.

Comment: Mark I have added the getdocument function to the code. It does return an object but inside that object is a table right? I could { print it out like this in the jsx } but I need to be able to append it to a div >.<

Comment: If i'm not wrong this is react.. And your `renderDocuments` is actually returning `JSX` and not HTML hence this behaviour. I would recpmmend doing it the react way.

Answer (score 1):

Your function returns a React Element. To render a React Element into a HTML Node, use `ReactDOM.render` (see [Rendering Elements](https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html)).

In your case it would be:

```js
const documentTableElement = this.renderDocuments();
const targetElement = document.getElementById('TableGoesHere');
ReactDOM.render(documentTableElement, targetElement);
```

Comment: This shows as [object Object] aswell, I will have to do it the react way it seems! By using { } to echo out the object as jsx/html